# Is it possible to allocate certain rows of data per thread in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

Can we achieve something like blocks in LR (as shown below) in JMeter, where if I have 100 rows of data, and I am running with 10 users, I want 1st user to pick data only from 1-10 rows, 2nd to pick only for 11 -20 rows, 3rd thread to pick 21-30, and so does 10th thread from 91-100 rows irrespective of no of iterations each thread does?
[image: ter]

Answer (score 1):

As of [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3) it's not possible using built-in configuration elements. I'm not aware of any plugins implementing this feature as well.

The only workaround I can think of is using [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) config element and [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) combination.

For example if you configure the Counter like:

[image]

You should be able to get the line from the CSV file according to your scenario with the following __groovy() function:

```
 ${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum() * 10 + (vars.get('counter') as int)),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I am getting error and it is executing only 1 iteration

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead

Comment: It indicates the sad fact of you not being able to configure a Counter looking at the image, if you need more comprehensive instructions consider getting familiarized with [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) article

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not for mocking me up on my competence. I did try various combinations and still see the issue. That's why reached out to stackoverflow.

Comment: FYI.. Working with JMeter for almost 3.5 years now. And there's no harm in asking a question be it simple or difficult. It's upto community to answer or not.

Comment: Ok, you're right, I made up the gif in GIMP, this is absolutely not possible, you will have to stick with LoadRunner